# SpaCy DisplaCy does not detect custom IOB tags

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I have an example text and IOB tags that I want to display using Displacy:

```
from spacy.tokens import Doc
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
tags = ['O', 'B-PER', 'I-PER']
words = ["I'm","John","Smith"]
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, ents=tags)
displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True)
```

However, Displacy visualizes the text like:

```
I'm John Smith (PER)
```

and not like :

```
I'm (O) John(B-Per) Smith (I-Per)
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way you can do this.

You want to show the literal IOB tag on every token. displaCy instead omits O tags (because they are the default) and shows whole entities, not token tags, because that's easier to understand. This is also the way all other graphical tools I'm aware of show tags (here's [brat](https://brat.nlplab.org/examples.html), for example). I am sure I've never seen a tool explicitly show O tags (how would that be useful?).

If you want to show every token with a tag I think you are better just printing text than using displaCy.